# Xstream and workaround for using reserved keywords as XML attributes. ("class")

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm trying to read an XML like this to an object using XStream:

```
    <behavior id="id384781" class="ChangeAttributeAction" enabled="true">
      <attributes>
        <text id="name">Change Attribute</text>
        <text id="bundleName">ChangeAttribute.behavior</text>
        <text id="targetAttribute">game.devices.touches.touch1.y</text>
        <text id="RHS">
          <expression>
            <string>acos(x)</string>
          </expression>
        </text>
      </attributes>
    </behavior>
```

Everything is working as they should except the `class="ChangeAttributeAction"` part.

I have in my Behavior class:

```
@XStreamAlias("class")
@XStreamAsAttribute
String classAtt = "";
```

Even tough I'm aliasing the field name, it gives the error:

**Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
ChangeAttributeAction : ChangeAttributeAction**

**---- Debugging information ----**

**message**             : ChangeAttributeAction

**cause-exception**     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException

**cause-message**       : ChangeAttributeAction

**class**               : projectmerger1.Behaviors

**required-type**       : projectmerger1.Behaviors

**converter-type**      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter

It used to work somehow, but now it doesn't. I used to treat objects differently but I cannot find out what I'm doing different to effect this. Also upon my research ->[link](http://xstream.10960.n7.nabble.com/Work-around-for-XStream-reserved-keywords-td3914.html)<- I learned that trying NO_REFERENCE mode might work, but it didn't in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
xstream.aliasSystemAttribute("", "class");
```

I have no idea why it works, but it works. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: An attribute named `class` has a special meaning to XStream - if you have a property with a particular declared type but the value you supply for that property is a subtype then XStream uses `class` to record the real type of the value.  This `aliasSystemAttribute` call disables this logic.